# Kubectl apply return certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I m using docker and kubernetes for deployment. When I try to deploy project.yaml file by running kubectl apply -f project.yaml I'm getting an error `Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid`.
I found here `https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ` that is is clock issue but I don't know how to sync local clock with server one. I tried manuali setting local clock to UK time(Where server is) but it does't work.

Comment: try to use ntpdate command and sync the server time as root user. `ntpdate us.pool.ntp.org`